# Concentration inequality for maximum permuted sums

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, concentration-of-measure

Let $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^n$ and $\{B_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be two sets of i.i.d. random variables (say Bernoulli's or sub-Gaussian). Assume that $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^n$ and $\{B_i\}_{i=1}^n$ are statistically independent as well. Consider the sum
$$
S_n = \max_{\pi\in\Pi_n}\sum_{i=1}^nA_iB_{\pi(i)},
$$
where $\pi$ is a permutation over $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and $\Pi_n$ is the set of all possible permutations. I am interested in "good" upper bounds on the tail probability, i.e., $\Pr(S_n>t)
$, for $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

One way to approach this is to use the union bound over $\Pi_n$, namely,
$$
\Pr(S_n>t)\leq n!\Pr\left(\sum_{i=1}^nA_iB_i>t\right),
$$
and then the probability term above can be easily upper bounded using the distributional assumptions on $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^n$ and $\{B_i\}_{i=1}^n$.

The question is whether there is an elegant way to deal this maximum other than just by applying a union bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any event $\omega\in \Omega$, according to the [rearrangement inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality)
$$\sum_{i=1}^n A_i(\omega)B_i( \omega) \le \sum_{i=1}^n A_{(i)}(\omega)B_{(i)}( \omega)$$
where $(A_{(i)})_{i=1,...,n}$ and $(B_{(i)})_{i=1,...,n}$  are the [order statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#Probabilistic_analysis) of $(A_{i})_{i=1,...,n}$ and  $(B_{i})_{i=1,...,n}$. In order words, the sum $\sum_{i=1}^n A_i(\omega)B_i( \omega)$ reaches its maximum when $(A_{i})_{i=1,...,n}$ and  $(B_{i})_{i=1,...,n}$ in the same order.

So, we have

$$\color{red}{S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n A_{(i)}B_{(i)}}  \tag{1}$$

---

**Case 1:** For the distribution like Bernoulli as in the question, I assume that these iid random variables $A_i$ and $B_i$ follow the distribution of the random variable $X$ with non-negative support.
We will apply the [Markov's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality#Statement) to $S_n$, given the assumption that these $A_i, B_i$ have non-negative support.
$$\mathbb{P}(S_n>t) \le\frac{\mathbb{E}(S_n)}{t}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}(A_{(i)}B_{(i)})}{t}= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}^2(A_{(i)})}{t} \tag{2}$$

For any $i \in \{1,2,...,n  \}$, according to this [result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#Cumulative_distribution_function_of_order_statistics), the density function of $A_{(i)}$ and $B_{(i)}$ are
$$f_{(i)}(x)=\frac{n!}{i!(n-i)!}f_X(x)F^{i-1}(x) (1-F(x))^{n-i}$$

Then, applying the [Cauchy-Schwazt inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#L2) (at the step 3-4), we have:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}^2(A_{(i)}) &= \left(\int_{0}^{+\infty} x f_{(i)}(x)dx\right)^2 \\
&=\left(\frac{n!}{i!(n-i)!}\right)^2\left(\int_{0}^{+\infty} x f_X(x)F^{i-1}(x) (1-F(x))^{n-i}dx\right)^2 \\
&=\left(\frac{n!}{i!(n-i)!}\right)^2\left(\int_{0}^{+\infty} (x \sqrt{f_X(x)})\sqrt{f_X(x)}F^{i-1}(x) (1-F(x))^{n-i}dx\right)^2 \\
& \le \left(\frac{n!}{i!(n-i)!}\right)^2 \left(\int_{0}^{+\infty} x^2 f_X(x)\right)\left(\int_{0}^{+\infty} f_X(x)F^{2i-2}(x) (1-F(x))^{2n-2i}dx\right)\\
& = \left(\frac{n!}{i!(n-i)!}\right)^2 (\mathbb{V}(X) + \mathbb{E}^2(X))\left(\int_{0}^{1} u^{2i-2} (1-u)^{2n-2i}du\right)\\
\end{align}$$

Then
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}^2(A_{(i)}) \le (\mathbb{V}(X) + \mathbb{E}^2(X)) \sum_{i=1}^n  \left( \left(\frac{n!}{i!(n-i)!}\right)^2  \int_{0}^{1} u^{2i-2} (1-u)^{2n-2i}du \right)  \tag{3}$$

From $(2),(3)$, we deduce that

$$\mathbb{P}(S_n>t) \le \frac{1}{t}(\mathbb{V}(X) + \mathbb{E}^2(X))\color{red}{\sum_{i=1}^n  \left( \left(\frac{n!}{i!(n-i)!}\right)^2  \int_{0}^{1} u^{2i-2} (1-u)^{2n-2i}du \right)} \tag{4}$$

The RHS of $(4)$ is a known function of $n$ and variance of $X$. We can make it a more elegant (but less tighter) by remarking that

$$\frac{n!}{i!(n-i)!} \le \frac{n!}{\left(\frac{n}{2} \right)!^2}$$

Then, the red term of $(4)$ is smaller than
$$ \le \frac{n!}{\left(\frac{n}{2} \right)!^2}\sum_{i=1}^n   \left(\frac{n!}{i!(n-i)!}  \int_{0}^{1} u^{2i-2} (1-u)^{2n-2i}du \right) \le \frac{n!}{\left(\frac{n}{2} \right)!^2} \int_{0}^{1} (u^2 + (1-u)^2)^n du$$

So, a more elegant bound of $(4)$ is
$$\color{red}{\mathbb{P}(S_n>t) \le \frac{1}{t}(\mathbb{V}(X) + \mathbb{E}^2(X))\frac{n!}{\left(\frac{n}{2} \right)!^2} \int_{0}^{1} (u^2 + (1-u)^2)^n du }\tag{5}$$

---

**Case 2:** For distribution of type sub-Gaussian  (that includes the Gaussian distribution)

Applying the [Chernoff's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound#The_generic_bound), we have:
$$\mathbb{P}(S_n >t) \le \inf_{s\ge 0}\frac{\mathbb{E}(e^{sS_n})}{e^{st}} \tag{6}$$

With $(1)$, we compute $\mathbb{E}(sS_n)$
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(e^{sS_n}) &= \mathbb{E}(e^{s\sum_{i=1}^n A_{(i)}B_{(i)}})\\
&= \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}\left(e^{s A_{(i)}B_{(i)}}\right)\\
&\le \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}\left(e^{\frac{s}{2} (A_{(i)}^2 +B_{(i)}^2)}\right) = \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}^2\left(e^{\frac{s}{2} A_{(i)}^2}\right) \tag{7}\\
\end{align}$$

We have, for $i=1,...,n$, applying the [Cauchy-Schwazt inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#L2) (at the step 3-4) as in the case 1:
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}^2\left(e^{\frac{s}{2} A_{(i)}^2}\right) &= \left(\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{\frac{sx^2}{2}} f_{(i)}(x)dx\right)^2 \\
&=\left(\frac{n!}{i!(n-i)!}\right)^2\left(\int_{0}^{+\infty} x f_X(x)F^{i-1}(x) (1-F(x))^{n-i}dx\right)^2 \\
&=\left(\frac{n!}{i!(n-i)!}\right)^2\left(\int_{0}^{+\infty} (e^{\frac{sx^2}{2}} \sqrt{f_X(x)})\sqrt{f_X(x)}F^{i-1}(x) (1-F(x))^{n-i}dx\right)^2 \\
& \le \left(\frac{n!}{i!(n-i)!}\right)^2 \left(\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{sx^2} f_X(x)dx\right)\left(\int_{0}^{+\infty} f_X(x)F^{2i-2}(x) (1-F(x))^{2n-2i}dx\right)\\
& = \mathbb{E}\left(e^{sX^2}  \right) \left(\frac{n!}{i!(n-i)!}\right)^2 \left(\int_{0}^{1} u^{2i-2} (1-u)^{2n-2i}du\right)\\
\end{align}$$

As $X$ follows the [sub-Gaussian distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sub-Gaussian_distribution), there exists a $\delta <+\infty$ such that $\mathbb{E}\left(e^{\delta X^2}  \right)<+\infty$, then, for all $0\le s \le \delta$, $\mathbb{E}\left(e^{s X^2}  \right)<+\infty$.

**Remark:** If $X$ follows the Gaussian distribution, $\delta$ can be $\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}$ where $\sigma^2$ is the variance of $X$.

Return back to $(7)$, we have for all $0\le s \le \delta$ :
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(e^{sS_n}) &= \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}^2\left(e^{\frac{s}{2} A_{(i)}^2}\right) \le \mathbb{E}^n\left(e^{sX^2}  \right) \underbrace{\prod_{i=1}^n  \left(\left(\frac{n!}{i!(n-i)!}\right)^2 \int_{0}^{1} u^{2i-2} (1-u)^{2n-2i}du\right)}_{\text{Let denote this term by } M}\\
\end{align}$$

From $(6)$, we have
$$\mathbb{P}(S_n >t) \le M\cdot \inf_{0 \le s \le \delta} \frac{\mathbb{E}^n\left(e^{sX^2}  \right) }{e^{st}} \tag{8}$$

If the exact distribution of the sub-Gaussian variable $X$ is not specified, we can be content to have
$$\mathbb{P}(S_n >t) \le M \mathbb{E}^n\left(e^{\delta X^2}  \right)\color{red}{e^{-\delta t}}  \tag{9}$$

From $(9)$, we can deduce that $S_n$ follows a heavy-tailed distribution.

Comment: Thanks! What about the case where the random variables can be negative, say all $A_i$'s and $B_i$'s are Gaussians.

Comment: @J.John this solution only works for non negative distribution, like Bernoulli distribution. We may extend it to the case where the support is bounded. For the case of gaussian, perhaps you need another approach.

Comment: I think for gaussian distribution, the tail probability is bounded by something like $C\cdot e^{-\gamma t}$. The approach is different

Comment: Interesting! Can you please edit your answer to account for the Gaussian case?

Comment: @J.John One of my masterpieces. Enjoy yourself ;)

Comment: I noticed to something that overlooked in my first reading. It seems that the equality above (7) relied on the fact that the ordered random variables $\{A_{(i)}\}$ are independent (and similarly $\{B_{(i)}\}$). Is this true (the original sequences $(A_i)$ and $(B_i)$ are i.i.d.)?

Comment: @J.John They are independent. A more general result is that, for whatever function $f$, we have $f(A_1, A_2,..,A_n)$ and $f(B_1, B_2,..,B_n)$ are independent as soon as $A_1, A_2,..,A_n$ and $B_1, B_2,..,B_n$ are independent.

Comment: It is clear to me that $A_{(1)},A_{(2)},...A_{(n)}$ are independent of $B_{(1)},B_{(2)},...B_{(n)}$. What I don't understand is why the sequence $A_{(1)},A_{(2)},...A_{(n)}$ form independent set of random variables, namely, why $A_{(1)}$ is independent of $A_{(2)}$, etc. The equality above (7) use this claim, right?

Comment: You talked about the third line of $(7)$ or the second line of $(7)$?
$$$$
If the second line of $(7)$, we have the product as $S_n = \sum A_{(i)}B_{(i)}$ (and **NOT** because $A_{(i)}$ and $A_{(j)}$ are independent, which is not true). 
$$$$
If the third line of $(7)$, **each term** of the product is equal to the product of $E(e^{\frac{s}{2}A^2_{(i)}})$ and $E(e^{\frac{s}{2}B^2_{(i)}})$ due to the independency of $A_{(i)}$ and $B_{(i)}$. And we have also, $E(e^{\frac{s}{2}B^2_{(i)}}) = E(e^{\frac{s}{2}A^2_{(i)}})$, then you have $(7)$.

Comment: I am asking why
$$
\mathbb{E}(e^{s\sum_{i=1}^n A_{(i)}B_{(i)}})= \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}\left(e^{s A_{(i)}B_{(i)}}\right)
$$
So you are claiming that the expectation of the product is the product of the expectations. For this you need the independency that I mentioned. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The random variable $S_n$ does concentrate (around its expectation by bounded differences inequality) but it does not concentrate around 0. Thus the desired probability of $P(S_n > t)$ might not be small for non-trivial $t$.

Let $A_i$, $B_i$ be i.i.d. Rademacher, i.e., uniform on $\{-1,1\}$. Then $A_iB_i$ is again a Rademacher random variable. For this setting, the union bound is vacuous for $t = o(n)$. (In fact, $t$ needs to be $\omega(n)$ to for it to be less than $1$, which is vacuous as $|S_n|\leq n$).

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be the fraction of $-1$'s in $A_i$'s and $B_i$'s, respectively.
With high probability, $\max(|\alpha-1/2|,|\beta-1/2|) \leq \Delta$, where $\Delta = O(1/\sqrt{n})$.

Now choose the permutation that sorts of both random variables in increasing order.
For this choice of permutation, the sum is at equal to $\min(\alpha,\beta) n + \min(1-\alpha, 1- \beta) n - n|\beta-\alpha| $, which is of the order $n - O(\Delta n)$.

Thus, with high probability $\leq 0 \leq n - S_n \leq O(\sqrt{n})$.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. What if we deal with Gaussian random variables?